# iOS Photo Library supported Media Formats

Tags: ios, swift, photo

Does anyone know of an official, reliable source of information about what image- and video file types are supported by the iOS photo library? Something like this but for iOS: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

I've been searching Google up and down but there is only a hogde podge of varying info and nothing really exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses a concept called Uniform Type Identifiers to identify files and data that can be transferred.

Given below link lists the standard types:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/system-declared_uniform_type_identifiers

Since these listed are standard types I am assuming they would be supported by the Photo library

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/system-declared_uniform_type_identifiers